# The spectrum of a polynomial of an operator, question about proof, why are the operators invertible?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

I have a question about a proof.

In the proof $\sigma(T)$ is $\{\lambda \in\mathbb{C}: T-\lambda I\text{ is not invertible}\}$.

In the proof they use this lemma:

[image]

Here is the proof, my problem is with the red equivalence:

[image]

By Lemma 4.35, the $\leftarrow$ is clear. But how do they get the $\rightarrow$
? How can he say that if the product is invertible, then each $T-\mu_jI$ is invertible?

As I have understood with we have to show that it is bounded, 1-1, and onto. It is easy to show that it is bounded by $\|T\|+|\mu_j|$. However, from general function theory, if $f_1f_2$ is bijective, we can only say that $f_2$ is 1-1, and $f_1$ is onto. So the only info I have is that all $T-\mu_jI$ is bounded(and linear). $T-\mu_nI$ is 1-1, $T-\mu_1I$ is onto, hence I am not able to show that even one of the $T-\mu_jI$ is invertible.

Can someone please help me with the $\rightarrow$?

Comment: Since all the $(T-\mu_j I)$ commute, you can conclude that all of them are 1-1 (not just $(T-\mu_n I)$ and all of them are onto (not just $(T-\mu_1 I)$). Thus all of them are invertible by the open mapping theorem.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Thank you very much, that was very clever!

Comment: Indeed, this statement is true in purely algebraic setting: The product of commuting elements $a_1,\dots,a_n$ in a ring is invertible if and only if each $a_i$ is invertible. The proof procedes by simply writing down the inverse: $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ and $a^{-1}=b(ab)^{-1}=(ab)^{-1}b$ and checking that it really is the inverse (for $n$ factors it's the same, i just didn't want to write out the longer formulas).

Answer (score 1):

If one of the members of the product was NOT invertible,it would map a sequence of vectors, that doesn't converge to zero, to a sequence converging to zero.But then the product would also do that, making the product non-invertible.

Comment: I don't understand your argument. It seems to imply that any linear right inverse is an inverse. But for example $$r:\ell^2(\mathbb{N})\rightarrow \ell^2(\mathbb{N}), (x_1, x_2, \dots)\mapsto (0, x_1, x_2,\dots)$$ $$l:\ell^2(\mathbb{N})\rightarrow\ell^2(\mathbb{N}), (x_1, x_2, \dots)\mapsto (x_2, x_3, \dots)$$ are both not invertible, but $l \circ r=id_{\ell^2(\mathbb{N})}$ is invertible.